# Enumerations and pattern matching

Tags: scala

Defined two enums as below.

```
object DimensionList1 extends Enumeration {
  type DimensionList1 = Value
  val Platform, Region, Service = Value

}

object DimensionList2 extends Enumeration {
  type DimensionList2 = Value
  val Platform, Region, Service, Scope = Value

}
```

Trying to do pattern matching based on the input enum. It looks like as soon as i add multiple case statements inside the initial dimension match, i cannot use "dimension.Platform" inside the second match statement. Compiler complains that "dimension.Platform - Symbol cannot be found" even though it is present in both enums.

```
def processFilters(supportedDimension: Enumeration, filters: List[FilterModel])= {
  val dimension = supportedDimension match {
      case DimensionList1 => DimensionList1
      case DimensionList2 => DimensionList2
      case _ => DimensionList1
  }

  // filters is a list of model [dimensionName, dimensionValues]

  for(filter <- filters) yield {
     util.Try(dimension.withName(filter.dimensionName)) match {

          case util.Success(dimension.Platform) => { ** This is not possible **
             // do something 
          }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create a Map which defines handlers for your different enum values:

```
val handlers: Map[Any, () => Unit] = HashMap(
  DimensionList1.Platform -> doSomethingForPlatform,
  DimensionList1.Region -> doSomethingForRegion,

  DimensionList2.Platform -> doSomethingForPlatform,
  DimensionList2.Region -> doSomethingForRegion,
  DimensionList2.Scope -> doSomethingForScope
)
```

Then adjust your code in processFilters the following way:

```
def processFilters(supportedDimension: Enumeration, filters: List[FilterModel])= {
    val dimension = supportedDimension
    for(filter <- filters) yield {
      Try(dimension.withName(filter.dimensionName)) match {
        case suc@Success(x) => {
          val handlerFunction = handlers.getOrElse(suc.get, () => {/* we have no handler defined in our handlers Map */})
          handlerFunction() // call the handler function
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

hope this helps!

Comment: What if i want to go through all the items and not just the common items.
For example, if the input is DimensionList1, then i need to do match check for all the items in DimensionList1 and similarly if input is DimensionList2, check all the items in DimensionList2. 

Your trait strategy works only for common items i believe.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea either, but:

```
scala> trait Dimensions { _: Enumeration =>
     |   val Platform, Region, Service = Value
     | }
defined trait Dimensions

scala> object Dim1 extends Enumeration with Dimensions
defined object Dim1

scala> object Dim2 extends Enumeration with Dimensions { val Scope = Value }
defined object Dim2

scala> def f(dims: Enumeration with Dimensions, name: String) = dims.withName(name) match {
     |   case dims.Platform => "platform"
     |   case Dim2.Scope    => "scope"
     | }
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Dim2.Value
 required: dims.Value
         case Dim2.Scope    => "scope"
                   ^

scala> def f(dims: Enumeration with Dimensions, name: String) = (dims.withName(name): Any) match {
     |   case dims.Platform => "platform"
     |   case Dim2.Scope    => "scope"
     | }
f: (dims: Enumeration with Dimensions, name: String)String

scala> f(Dim1, "Region")
scala.MatchError: Region (of class scala.Enumeration$Val)
  at .f(<console>:15)
  ... 29 elided

scala> f(Dim1, "Platform")
res1: String = platform

scala> f(Dim1, "Scope")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value found for 'Scope'
  at scala.Enumeration.$anonfun$withName$2(Enumeration.scala:125)
  at scala.Enumeration.withName(Enumeration.scala:125)
  at .f(<console>:13)
  ... 29 elided

scala> f(Dim2, "Scope")
res3: String = scope
```

The type mismatch says don't do this; upcasting to `Any` is not a workaround so much as a way to say "I don't care any more."

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesnot work because:

```
  val dimension = supportedDimension match {
      case DimensionList1 => DimensionList1
      case DimensionList2 => DimensionList2
      case _ => DimensionList1
  }
```

In above code, you are returning different type, i.e. either `DimensionList1` or `DimensionList2` therefore, scala will assing type of `dimension` to `Enumeration`. Hence, you cannot access value of enumeration, such as: `dimension.Platform` because `Enumeration` is an abstract class does not have your values : Platform, Region, Service etc.

So, you need first cast the dimension to appropriate enumeration in order to access its value:

```
  dimension.isInstanceOf[DimensionList1.type] match {
    case true => {
      val dimen = dimension.asInstanceOf[DimensionList1.type]
      dimen.Platform  //now you have access to enumvalues...
      //code for your filter
    }
    case false => {
      dimension.isInstanceOf[DimensionList2.type] match {
        case true => {
          val dimen = dimension.asInstanceOf[DimensionList2.type]
          dimen.Platform  //now you have access to enum values...
          //code for your filter
        }
        case false =>
          //do something...
      }
    }
  }

      //Another approach.
      dimension match {
        case x: DimensionList1.type => {
          x.Platform //now you have access to enumvalues...
          //code for your filter
        }
        case x: DimensionList2.type => {
          x.Scope //now you have access to enumvalues...
          //code for your filter      
        }
        case //match for more cases.
      }
```

Comment: Now i understand the root cause. But this solution is going to create a lot of case statements in my inner match/case block. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You need to handle each enum type class explicitly, so you need to resolve each type and and do filter for each type. I have update answer with another approach, hope it will help.

Comment: I prefer the second approach as more idiomatic, though someone said they like explicit `isInstanceOf/asInstanceOf`. Both test `eq`.